# Ohm's law Vs. Ohm's relation (which one is right)?

Tags: circuit-analysis, analog, ohms-law, vlsi

Ok, so this might be a stupid question but I just had to ask.

We are all taught that Ohm's law is:

V = IR

I have heard some people that insist that it should be called Ohm's relation instead of calling it Ohm's law.

Is there really any difference between the two phrases?

Comment: Have you asked the people suggesting to call it a relation why they say that? I'm sure they have a reason--it may be a bad reason, or it may be a good one, but without hearing their reasoning all I can say is that it doesn't seem like it would matter.

Comment: No, it's the same equation and the same physical law.

Comment: Ignore those people.   Some folks feel the need to show how smart they are.   If you're gonna be a physicist, maybe you can call it a 'relation'.  Don't show up at any EE event and say that though, folks will look at you like your face is painted orange.

Comment: You all probably right. I had a professor a few years ago in EE who insisted on why it's wrong to call it ohm's law and how it should be called ohm's relation. I don't remember his explanation since I didn't understand it at that time. I have heard that the other day from another student who said that I was wrong for calling it ohm's law and not ohm's relation. None of them could give a convincing explanation for why that is. I just thought I should ask in case the problem was with me.

Comment: "Ohm's Relation" sounds odd, like one is talking about some family member of Georg Ohm. "Oh you know Ohm's relation? His brother Simon..." Scientific _laws_ are based on repeated observations and tests. People seem to confuse that term with the legal term, which is a human-imposed rule or stipulation. Not at all _related_.

Comment: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/ohmlaw.html#c1

Answer (score 3):

Direct quote from [Wikipedia article about Georg Ohm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georg_Ohm) (emphasis mine):

> Ohm found that there is a direct proportionality between the potential difference (voltage) applied across a conductor and the resultant electric current. **This relationship is known as Ohm's law.**

In scientific terms, a "[law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_law)" is a statement or formula based on observation and measurement. This is quite different from a legal statute or law which humans create as part of societal regulation.

From the article on scientific laws (also my emphasis):

> It is generally understood that [scientific laws] implicitly **reflect**, though they do not explicitly **assert**, causal relationships fundamental to reality...

It is my opinion that those suggesting "Ohm's Law" be referred to as "Ohm's Relation" are confused about the definition of a law as it is used in science.

While Ohm's Law is an observation about the *relationship* of electrical properties, it is not itself a "relation." Many other laws in science which describe relationships are not called "relations." Newton's Law (of motion) describes the relationship between force, mass, and acceleration, but it isn't referred to as "Newton's Relation."

Answer (score 2):

It is called a 'law' however ohms law is an experimental/empirical observed relationship that works for *most materials*. Ohms law does not apply to non-ohmic materials, or materials that don't follow this relationship, memristors and batteries being among some of those non-ohmic materials.

Answer (score 1):

I've never considered Ohm's law to be a *law*, not in the sense that physicists assign that term, but instead simply a *descriptive* category that is based upon a practical separation in derived circumstances from the application of known physical theory to specific experimental situations.

Some boundary distinctions are entirely arbitrary and human-imposed, such as the difference between a taxable and non-taxable item or event.

Some distinctions change over time as the application of known physical theory changes, such as the more modern boundary distinction that separates planets from dwarf planets -- where the early prescription was little more than arbitrary as now seen through a better understanding of how solar systems form. (This distinction is now 5 to 6 orders of magnitude between a planet and a dwarf planet and it is through better observation and better application of theory that this gap was uncovered and we realized that nature was showing us a very wide span between the two.)

And some boundary distinctions are practical ones, such as Ohm's law, as this helps determine the applicable tools for analysis.

Answer (score 0):

Typically in physics, "law" refers to something that is fundamental. Unlike Maxwell's equations, Ohm's Law is not a fundamental law, it's an empirically found linear relation between voltage and current for *Ohmic conductors*. For example, if you hold an open circuit voltage, why doesn't a constant current flow through the air, even if infinitely small? Air is a dielectric, so a voltage applied will just create dipole moments, until the voltage is so high that it rips the electrons from their nuclei and allows current to briefly flow.

There is a version of this that is a fundamental law, and that's Kirchoff's reformulation of Ohm's Law, \$\mathbf{J}=\sigma \mathbf{E} \$ where J is the current density vector, E is the electric field vector, and sigma is the material conductivity.

So because of this some people will call it Ohm's relation, but no one I know calls it that. Maybe it's just a physicist thing, us engineers tend to be less precise.

Answer (score -1):

#### TL;DR: Someone with a elementary school level "understanding" of scientific language tries to "fix" things. News at 11.

> which one is right

It's not even a question.

---

"Ohm's law" is a well-entrenched phrase. It's an idiom. It doesn't literally mean that it's some "law". It's an idiom just as "laws of motion" is, or like "road works" is. Ever saw a "Road Works" sign? Ever thought what nonsense it is, at first glance?

[image: A road street sign, displaying ROAD WORKS AHEAD text.]

[image: A leaflet of 1960's UK road signs, including ROAD WORKS warning sign.]

Yet, somehow, everyone at some point develops an understanding of what's meant by a sign with "Road Works Ahead" written on it. And just like that, everyone who is learning science is, at some point, supposed to understand that Nature is not a person. We don't make laws that *direct it*. Our "laws of Nature" are **descriptions** of Nature. That's what the word "law" means when you or me speak of Nature. Just as the word "works" in the phrase "Road Works Ahead" doesn't mean that the road is performing its duty adequately ahead, nor that the road is employed in some job.

People who try to rename "law" into a "relation" don't understand how the language works - language that has been used that way in science for centuries now. Nobody who has any understanding of science considers Ohm's Law some literal law that the Nature has to "obey". And anyone who has ever dealt with science should well know that all we got to describe Nature are approximations, with understood limits of applicability.